# how to use slidingDrawer be scrolling left and right

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I want to implement right left scrolling. 
When the user doing left or right just to show him next or before sell on the array on my text view. 
I think I need to use for this slidingDrawer  but I dont want to use buttons for this.
If you can send some code to look how to do it I will be glad.

Here my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pubdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing it very simple without importing a lot of code and icons....
The simplest way that I fond is this:

http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-swipe-gesture-implementation/